# iOS - Display system time in nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

Okay, I am building an app for `iOS` and I am having some trouble with getting the current time to display properly within a `UILabel`.
Here is the code in the `ViewController.h` file:

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabelStandbyScreen;

 -(void)updateLabel;

 -(void)updateTime;

 @end

 @interface updateTime : NSDate

 @end
```

I'm new to `Obj-C` and I was playing around with it to see if I could fix the problem. Everything is fine in this file it's the .m that has the problems.

**ViewController.m:**

```
@interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self updateLabel];
 }

 -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(void)updateTime
 {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    _timeLabelStandbyScreen.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];

    [self preformSelector:@selector(updateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
 }

 @end
```

I'm sure the problem is really simple and I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: There's a typo in your "preformSelector..." method.

I'm not sure what is not working. Is it because the label is not updated every one second? You need a NSTimer and use it like: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; Make sure you invalidate the NSTimer when you're not using it anymore.

Comment: Thanks @rocir! That worked. I commented out the preformSelector method and added the NSTimer and it got rid of the error.

Comment: add your answer so that will help all others Mr. Jake1k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By commenting out the preformSelector method and adding a NSTimer (like @rocir suggested) it correctly displayed the time.